# YouTube v3 playlists 'list' call is returning an empty list and this used to return a default ID if no playlists were defined in channel

Tags: youtube-data-api

https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet,status&mine=true&maxResults=5

And even defining a `channelId` in this request returns an empty list so I cannot query any videos in this channel. There are videos in this channel, they are not in any playlist and there are no playlists defined. We used to be able to get the videos that were in a channel that were not in any playlist, so I believe there was a `playlistId` being returned when no playlists were defined. This was working this morning.

I've tried every variation of this API call, and like I said, I'm no stranger to YouTube v3 API's. This was working and now it's not. What changed?

Comment: *defining a channelId in this request returns an empty list* may you provide the URL you tried?

Comment: https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet,status&channelId=UCCULIMRLzGx3K0R0uFFdF6A&maxResults=5

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me what response you were accustomed with, can you share an example JSON that you previously received and that you do not receive as such anymore?

Answer (score 0):

It was unclear previously that we were actually searching videos in a channel and getting back these outside of querying based on playlistId. I apologize. Ignore this question!